# FileReader returns empty result for file from the bundle

Tags: iphone, cordova, filereader

I've tried to read a file from the app bundle using phonegap's `FileReader` class:

```
...
loadFile: function (path, callback) {
   fileReader = new FileReader(); 

   fileReader.onerror = function () {
     ...
   }

   fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
     callback(evt.target.result);
   }

   fileReader.readAsText("./www/" + path); 
}
```

In this example path is something like "index.html". The `onerror` callback is never called. `onload` is called but `evt.target.result` is empty. Do you have any suggestions? Is it in general possible to read files from the bundle with the phonegap API? Can I use relative paths like "./www/foo.txt"?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path that is passed into `readAsText` is relative to the "Documents" folder in the applications sandbox. Hence you have to simply fix the path by replacing the line

```
fileReader.readAsText("./www/" + path);
```

with

```
fileReader.readAsText("./../myApp.app/www/" + path);
```

to access the file. This works for me.